# AVIO write multiple mp4 segments to buffer

Tags: ffmpeg, libav

I'm using ffmpeg for muxing into mp4 files, and using avio for writing output to memory buffer but not disk and it works pretty fine with one file, but it doesn't if I want multiple segments to be outputted over custom IO to memory buffer.

So is it possible to output "segments" with ffmpeg custom IO to buffer?

Comment: Ffmpeg is open source, which makes anything possible!

Comment: As a quick solution, I manually checked for segment duration and recreate muxer for each segment.